# Getting a 'friendly' error message for an exception

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to connect to database and if there is anything wrong I throw an exception:

```
class Ex_cnt extends Exception{}
class Ex_slct extends Exception{}
$server = "localhost";
$usr = "root";
$pss = "*******";
$db = "learn";
try{
        $cnt = mysqli_connect($server,$usr,$pss);
        if(!$cnt){
            throw new Ex_cnt("wrong in database details");
        }
        $dbslct = mysql_select_db($db);
        if(!$dbslct){
            throw new Ex_slct("wrong database name");
        } 
}
catch(Ex_cnt $error_cnt){
        echo $error_cnt->getMessage();
}
catch(Ex_slct $error_slct){
        echo $error_slct->getMessage();
}
```

the problem is that this code shows the following error

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in D:\xampp\htdocs\learn\index.php on line 10
>   Unable to connect

I want it to just show

> Unable to connect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should turn off the `display_errors` in production environment.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);  
error_reporting(E_ALL); // While error reporting should remain at full force
```

Answer (score -1):

Try and use:

```
$cnt = @mysqli_connect($server,$usr,$pss);
```

Comment: For god sake !DON'T SUPPRESS ERRORS!! this is about as bad as advise gets! Also, supressing errors doesn't fix a failure to connect

Comment: @OmarMoustafa: Not only aren't you addressing the issue (not being able to connect), using `@` to suppress an error means that error won't be logged as _"the error never really occured"_ as far as PHP is concerned. This means that clients/users don't get the requested data, but whoever checks the logs to find out why they keep getting feedback that the site is _down_ has no clue where to look

Comment: the @ equals display_errors=0 ... "the error never really occured" is false. It can be logged and it happens. Read the manual.

Comment: @OmarMoustafa: your catch blocks only echo the message, you're still not even close to finding out why you're unable to connect in the first place

Comment: He asked a question and i'v given him the easiest implementation for his case... he can write custom error handling if that is what he wants.

Comment: this is just TEST, i will put my functions later

Comment: @Udan: `If the track_errors feature is enabled, any error message generated by the expression will be saved in the variable $php_errormsg. This variable will be overwritten on each error, so check early if you want to use it.` <-- you _can_ log the error, but it's up to you if it is logged or not. [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) mention other things you have to take into account. All of them have the word _if_ in them too many times

Comment: and how is this any different then what i'v said? The error happens and it can be logged.